# How to write $X \iff Y$ in CNF form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that $X \iff Y$ is true when

1. $X$ is True and $Y$ is True
2. $X$ is False and $Y$ is False

I know that there is a simple algorithm to convert to CNF form, but I don't remember it...

Comment: How about $(X \land Y) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y) = (\lnot X \lor Y) \land (X \lor \lnot Y)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(x \leftrightarrow y) \Leftrightarrow (x \rightarrow y) \land (y \rightarrow x) \Leftrightarrow (\lnot x \lor y) \land (\lnot y \lor x)  $$

Comment: There is a distinction between $\rightarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$, the former is a connective between propositions *within* the language, while the latter is in the meta-language. This also made your post somewhat easier to read :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila,תודה

Answer (score 3):

$(\neg X \vee Y)\wedge(X\vee\neg Y)$